# Windows Server 2012R2 - RemoteFX - Do I need to create a VM for this?

Tags: windows-server-2012, remotefx

Can I enable RemoteFX on remote sessions on the server? (RDP)
I mean, I don't want to run an extra virtual machine with all the hassle, but use my server with RemoteFX.

Is that possible?

OS / host: Windows Server 2012R2 Datacenter
I have installed DirectX, drivers and everything else, in order to be able to run 3D applications.
(And they do work perfectly.)

Comment: [RemoteFX vGPU Setup and Configuration Guide for Windows Server 2012](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/16652.remotefx-vgpu-setup-and-configuration-guide-for-windows-server-2012.aspx): I'm going to go with "No". :)

Comment: Last week I set up a test workstation (Dell T3600 w/128GB SSD & 8GB Memory) with Windows 2012 Server RDS with RemoteFX with no virtual machines. I was impressed with the quality and speed (LAN) with 3 monitors at extreme high resolution (5MP: 2560x2048).

Comment: @Logman: Yeah, RemoteFX is impressive without vGPU. But the question here is the vGPU support. Guess I will grab an enterprise image according to techie007 and give it a shot. Wonder how my PC will handle a 3D app running outside and one inside.

Comment: I wasn't positive either before or after, all info was about vdi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is... Last week I set up a test workstation (Dell T3600 w/128GB SSD & 8GB Memory) with Windows 2012 Server RDS with RemoteFX with no virtual machines. Proof of concept. I was impressed with the quality and speed (LAN/WAN) with 3 monitors at extreme high resolution (5MP: 2560x2048).

Workstation

- Dell T3600 w/ Samsung 840 Pro 128GB SSD

OS:

- Windows 2012 Server R2 w/ Remote Desktop Services & RemoteFX

GFX Card:

- AMD FirePro V4900 1GB 128-bit GDDR5 PCI Express 2.1 x16 Workstation
  Video Card

Remote Hosts I use to test was basically the same, but running Win7 with latest RDP (v8). I still need to test the "LOSSLESS" feature.